# Finding an index and value in a array

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, indexof

I have this property with some value and I'm getting a List of strings. I need to check in every string of this list for a match with "input" and store the value and the index in a Dictionary. Can somebody help me?

```
public string[] input = { "18", "30", "31", "34", "42", "32", "87", "03",
    "78", "79", "59", "04", "69", "81", "98", "61", "96", "90", "89", "77",
    "01", "62", "12", "22", "23", "11", "57", "07" };
```

This is what I tried:

```
public void ReceiveValues(List<string> inputData)
{
    foreach (var item in inputData)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var index = Array.IndexOf(input, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of a value you can use

```
int index = input.IndexOf("input string");
```

Or

```
int index = 0;
string searchvalue = "input string";
for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (searchvalue == input[i])
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

And then you can simply add this to a dictionary like so.

```
Dictionary<int,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>();


dictiionary.Add(index,input[index]);
```

If you need any help just ask ^_^

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm getting home to try this way ^^